# How can I build mobile apps from my Gatsby web app?

Tags: cordova, mobile, gatsby, phonegap, capacitor

I have built a Gatsby web app and am now trying to build an Android and iOS mobile app from the same code base.

Is there a way to do this, maybe with Apache Cordova / Capacitor? And if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible!

[Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/), the spiritual successor to Apache Cordova and Adobe PhoneGap, can be used for this purpose.

**For an existing project:**

1. Install and configure Capacitor as described in its [Getting Started docs](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/dependencies/).
2. Change the `webDir` to `public` in the `capacitor.config.json` file.
3. Add the required platforms and run the app on your mobile device.

Check out this article about [building fast mobile apps using Gatsby and Capacitor](https://react-freelancer.ch/blog/build-mobile-apps-using-gatsby-and-capacitor) for a more detailed step by step manual.

**For a new project:**

If you are planning to build a new hybrid app using Gatsby and Capacitor you might want to use the [gatsby-starter-capacitor](https://github.com/flogy/gatsby-starter-capacitor) Gatsby starter to speed up the process.

Just run `gatsby new my-gatsby-capacitor-project https://github.com/flogy/gatsby-starter-capacitor` to get a fully functional Gatsby app that can be run on mobile and that even uses native functionality.